# How to run eXist-db from CD-ROM

Tags: exist-db

how i can run exist-db from cd-rom for distribution?
I've googled for resource but anything found.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

eXist-db requires a filesystem to write data into, think of storing uploaded data, logfiles, transaction logs. SO you need to have a Harddrive or network drive anyway.

In the old days (...) it was actually possible to run eXist-db from a CD or DVD, but I am pretty sure this does not work any more (cause: we don't test it; it would require some config changes anyway)

Answer (score 0):

eXist-DB is a database management system. You would need something to run it on such as XAMPP. So no, you won't be able to run it straight from the DVD.

Comment: There's Jetty embedded with exist-db. If i execute start.jar on local machine (from any location) everything works properly but if i copy the entire exist-db folder on cd and then run it, i get the error "ERROR (BrokerPool.java [configure]:267) - Unable to initialize database instance 'exist': can't get database backend NATIVE".